# Repeated measures analysis where fixed effect changes within subjects

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures

I have sales data from a set of stores that are involved in a tournament-like competition where each week's average invoice amount is used to determine whether or not a store advances to the following week. (e.g., If store A > store B, then store A advances to week 2.) I need to find a way to assess what the average impact of being in the competition has on stores' average invoice amount. My dependent variable is the difference between each store's average invoice (for each week) and the store's average invoice over a 6-month pre-period. Once a store is eliminated, it does not close, so there is still sales data being collected. My hypothesis is that once a store is eliminated, the absence of the competition will cause its results post-elimination to regress back to the store's pre-period mean. How do I do this type of repeated measure analysis where the treatment (in this case remaining in the competition) may change throughout the course of collecting observations for each store? Thanks.